# Group by a common coloumn in a number of tables which are listed in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a db with the following structure. each row in my institution table has a daily info saved in a separate table. what we want is how to query db such that we obtain the sum of price column of each institution info table grouped by corresponding days in `_info` tables. my db is MySQL.

Table `institutions` :

```
id | institution_name | institution_info_table_name
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | "A"              | "A_info"
-----------------------------------------------------
2  | "B"              | "B_info"
```

Table `A_info` :

```
id | date       | price 
-----------------------
1  | 2013/02/12 | 12
-----------------------
2  | 2013/02/13 | 20
```

Table `B_info` :

```
id | date       | price 
-----------------------
1  | 2013/02/12 | 30
-----------------------
2  | 2013/02/13 | 50
```

output :

```
    date       | price 
    ------------------
    2013/02/12 | 42
    ------------------
    2013/02/13 | 70
```

Edit :

I tried following query but it did not work right :

```
"select sum( A_info.price) ,A_info.date from A_info,B_info group by date"
```

Comment: Looks like a simply query. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple , try as

```
select
x.date,
sum(x.price) as price
from
(
  (
    select 
    date,
    sum(price) as price
    from A_info
    group by date
  )
  union all
  (
    select
    date,
    sum(price) as price
    from B_info
    group by date
  )
)x
group by x.date
```

Comment: Thanks pal, it was a great job but I need to create this query dynamically based on rows in my `institutions` table. can you please update your query to do that?

Comment: so you may have many more values in institutions like C - C_info , D-D_info etc ?

Comment: Yes I have 100s of them!

Comment: no this is not going to workout this way, even if you do join you need to know the table names prior join. Now could you clarify a bit about your dynamic part ? And how you decide which tables to be looked for data retrieve ?

Comment: By dynamic I meant to get all info table names from `institutions` table, and contents of this table may change during the lifetime of my app. so decision is always the same: to retrieve data from all tables listed in `institutions` table.

Comment: if "institution_info_table_name" column is dynamic you cant do it in a one sql statement. it can be done in two sql statement , at first you have to extract table names from "instutution => institution_info_table_name"(first query)and put in a string  , then the main query which get the price grouped by date and have the made string in the from clause

Comment: Well You need to normalize the table, if I have to make this i would have `institutions` table as `(id , name ,active = 0,1)` another table to store the date wise values as  `institutions_info` with `(id PK, id_institutions, date , price)` so the caluclation would be so easy with JOIN and group by.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Thanks, I prefer your previous answer and divide the queries because my tables data are enormous (1 million per year).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this basic query?

```
select A_info.price+B_info.price from A_info, B_info where A_info.id=B_info.id and 
A_info.data=B_info.date;
```

Comment: Thanks. but I need to group by by date.